# Customize the Add Location Box : Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: sharepoint, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a requirement where I need to auto fill the values in the Add Document Location Box when a User clicks on Documents in the Dynamics CRM 2016. I don't think there is an out of the box way to do this. Any hints or suggestions are appreciated. 
[image]

I tried creating a sharepoint document location record on creating the record. When I click on Documents, it tries to find the URL for the location and gives an error that the location does not exist. I had hoped that the sharepoint folder will be created once the Sharepoint document location record has been created and associated with the record but that is not the case.
In case you have ever faced this problem, or if you have an alternative solution, please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In CRM 2016 you can [enable server-based SharePoint integration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531154.aspx). As a side note, in previous versions of CRM the [List Component](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40345) was required for the functionality you describe, but that is [now deprecated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2015/05/15/dynamics-crm-2015-update-1-list-component-deprecation/).

When clicking on Documents on a SharePoint enabled record, you will see a popup similar to the following after enabling the server-based SharePoint integration:

[image: Server Based SharePoint Integration Popup]

Comment: Hi Henrik, Thank you for the answer. By default, sharepoint will create the folder with a name like name_guid. The reason I was trying to auto fill the boxes is so that I can specify the sharepoint path and the name. The name in my case is based on certain attributes in the entity. I did remove the list components and the popup showed up, however, the path and the name which shows up needs to be changed. So far, I haven't found a way to do that and I will probably end up writing code in the plugin to access sharepoint and create the folders.

Comment: Oh, good that you already know that. I have previously used the approach of creating Document Location records with a plugin OnCreate, so that should be feasible.

Comment: I ended up writing plugin code which creates the folder in sharepoint at the path specified when a document location record is created. Thanks for helping out.